# What is the best way to cache JSON in redis-cache from nodejs service?

Tags: node.js, json, node-redis

We are trying to cache JSON response (size 1kb to 100 MB) object to redis from NodeJS service, What is the most efficient way to achieve that? (Our current implementation uses elastic-search for caching and we are trying to move to redis-cache)

We have tried using rejson with node-redis client, but it is not performant as compared to elastic search for large size data.

Comment: I use https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis and it works fine for me. To save data in a key of redis you need to stringify the JSON.